# Rendering pdf blob on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I asked a similar question on another thread and i got an answer that worked for firefox but not chrome, because chrome blocks popups.

I tried using a button to open the file but the file is not redered.

```
<div class="uploadButtonSection">
    <input type="image" src="clip.png" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" multiple
             accept="application/pdf" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="5MB" class="uploadIcon"/>

     <ul class="uploadList">
         <li ng-repeat="file in files" style="font:smaller">   
             <div class="attachmentIcon">
                 <img src="pdf-icon.png" ng-click="openFile(file)">
                 <div class="customBtn" ng-click="removeFile(file)">Remove</div>
                 {{file.name}}
             </div>     
         </li>
     </ul>
```

```
$scope.openFiles = function(file){
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        window.open(url,"_blank");
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(file, {type: 'application/pdf'}));
window.open(url);
```

Comment: The only change i did to your advice was turning it into an array, because i guess the constructor needs an iterable, but i still get the blank page



var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
window.open(url);